# How can I turn my search results into links in php?

Tags: php, search, hyperlink

My search is running perfectly but I need to link each result to a description page. Any ideas as to how to do it?

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'login.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$dbase);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Failure to connect".mysqli_connect_error());               
    }
    $id = $_SESSION['twitcher'];
    $srch = $_POST['searchstr'];
    $sql = "select * from gallery where title like '%$srch%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
       while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $rows['title'].$br.$br;
        }       
    }else echo "No posts found.";
    mysqli_close($conn);        

?>
```

Comment: echo the html for a link

Comment: Do you have Google in your country ? http://goo.gl/LwFVtb

Comment: what's `$br`? looks undefined. that's a sidenote btw - predefined `<br>`?

Comment: i wondered that to `$br='<br>';` perhaps. silly but i have seen it

Comment: yes the $br is a predefined <br/>

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as [*@Dagon stated*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315173/how-can-i-turn-my-search-results-into-links-in-php#comment48725734_30315173): You need to simply echo out a link tag (`<a>`)

```
while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<a href='/link_to_where_you_want_to_go'>" . $rows['title'] . "</a>" . $br . $br;
}
```

Comment: perhaps even: `echo "<a href='/link_to_where_you_want_to_go.php?id=$rows['id']'>$rows['title']</a>" . $br . $br;`

Comment: @Dagon I don't think so...

Comment: Don't you remember the days when you'd post a question and not come back and interact with it @Dagon?... yeah me neither ;-P

Comment: @Darren may be its a rhetorical question ;-)

Comment: question should be reopened though, leaving room for other answers

Comment: @Fred-ii- agreed on that